# Why I getting error Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'void' and 'float'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I Try to Set value of rb.AddForce(firePoint.forward.Set(newX, newY, newZ) I getting following error Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'void' and 'float'. I'm realy not sure what to do with this problem.
Ps: This is my first question on Stack Overflow so my apologizes if I asked somehow wrong, but yeah that is what is.

```
// New Input System
Player inputActions;
// Bullet stuff
public Transform firePoint;
public GameObject bulletPrefab;
public float bulletForce = 20f;
// Flash stuff
public Transform flashPos;
public GameObject flashPrefab;
// New Bullet Rotation
private float newX = 90;
private float newY = 0;
private float newZ = 0;

private void Awake()
{
    inputActions = new Player();
    inputActions.Enable();
    

    // You can define a function to handle the press
    inputActions.PlayerMain.Shoot.performed += ctx => Fire();

    // You can define a function to handle the press
   // Inputs.Player.OtherAction.performed += FunctionThatRuns();
}



private void Fire()
{
    //print("Boom!");
    // For Bullet
    AudioManager.instance.Play("Shoot");
    GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
    Rigidbody rb = bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    // Part when I getting error Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'void' and 'float'
    rb.AddForce(firePoint.forward.Set(newX, newY, newZ) * bulletForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
    // For Flash
    GameObject flashEffect = Instantiate(flashPrefab, flashPos.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    Destroy(flashEffect, 0.1f);
}
```

Comment: obviously `Set` does not return anything, it only sets a value, but does not return it. Of course you can´t multiply nothing with a float. What number do you expect `Set` to return?

Comment: `forward.Set()` does not return a value. You're trying to pass `void` or "no value" to a method `AddForce` that expects a Vector3 argument. This should solve it. 

By the way, it's an easy thing to google even if you're a beginner, so down-voted for not showing enough research effort. But don't let this dishearten you, and good luck on your learning journey :)

Comment: Looks like return type of `firePoint.forward.Set` is void and you add trying to multiply it with `bulletForce` which is float, that's why you are getting this error.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Well I trying to set custom position for bullet when I use 'firePoint.forward' I can't do anything in Unity editor so I think that I need to set custom values of X rotation for Bullet. I'm realy not sure what I need to do achieve that.

Comment: @HarshdeepSingh Hey buddy I already Googled everything for this topic and well I not found the answer so I decided to ask this question. And also I hope this question will help somebody one day if they stuck. Like I'm right now. :)

Comment: Try googling the compiler error next time. "Operator '*' cannot..." search gave me easy answers.

Comment: `Why I getting error Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'void' and 'float'` .. because you can't do that ... What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @HarshdeepSingh Well I already google my compiler error and I found no clear answer for my problem so maybe I'm first who have this problem. I don't know maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Well are you trying to use the forward vector (`rb.AddForce(firePoint.forward * bulletForce, ForceMode.Impulse);` or are you trying to set it `firePoint.forward = new Vevtor3 (newX, newY, newZ);`? .. Both would be two separate lines of code ;)

Comment: @derHugo Well to rotate my Bullet by X axis by 90 degrees. When I shoot the Bullet , bullet  x rotation is by default (firePoint.forward)  0 so I already tried in Unity editor to give by X 90 degrees rotation and well that is not fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already explained often enough now `Vector3.Set` is a `void` that doesn't return anything -> you can't multiply it by a `float`.

You only want to use

```
firePoint.forward * bulletForce
```

in order to shoot the bullet in the direction of the `firePoint.forward` vector.

It sounds like what you are trying to do is additionally rotating the bullet by 90° on the **local** X axis before shooting it.

You want to do that in different steps:

```
// Uses the bullets local space by default
bullet.transform.Rotate(90, 0, 0);  

rb.AddForce(firePoint.forward * bulletForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
```

Comment: Thank you buddy from deeply of my heart this solution is fixed my problem. :)

Answer (score -1):

Since this doesn't seem it's going to be closed right now, and you can't follow the comments, I'm answering it here.

Your error occurs at `rb.AddForce(firePoint.forward.Set(newX, newY, newZ) * bulletForce, ForceMode.Impulse);`, so let's break this expression down into multiple statements. It's equivalent to:

```
var setResult = firePoint.forward.Set(newX, newY, newZ); //1
var totalForce = setResult * bulletForce; //bulletForce is a "float"
rb.AddForce(totalForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
```

The problem is at `//1`. `forward.Set` does not return any value, so that assignment is wrong. What you're trying to do is multiply `void` (i.e., "no type" or "no value") with a `float` value. This violates basic language rules.

What the compiler error is telling you is that it (rightly) couldn't find an operator in the codebase that defines how to multiply two values of types `void` and `float`.

So, the real question here is, what are you expecting `forward.Set()` to return, and how do you find that value, since that method call is **not going to return anything for you to use**.

Here's what the code should look like (in expanded form):

```
firePoint.forward.Set(newX, newY, newZ);
Vector3 direction = /* ____ */;
Vector3 totalForce = direction * bulletForce;
rb.AddForce(totalForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
```

Now, you tell me what goes at `/* ____ */`. I suspect it's `firePoint.forward`, but only you can confirm it.

Comment: `firePoint.forward.Set(newX, newY, newZ);` won't work as expected .. it will set the values only in the vector **returned** by the property `firePoint.forward`, it will not assign the new values to that property => it will not actually rotate the object at all. In particular it will also not solve OPs actual intempt of rotating the bullet by 90° on the X axis ...

Comment: Yes, you're correct. He needs to set `firePoint.forward = VectorFromAngles(newX, newY, newZ)`. Furthermore, it still won't solve his problem, as setting only `forward` will cause the transform to rotate from current forward to new forward directly (its rotation on forward axis will be based on that).

However, **that is not what this question is about.**

Comment: No not at all ... he doesn't want to change the rotation of `firePoint` but rather of the spawned bullet .. also setting the forward vector to `90,0,0` is just the same as setting it to `1,0,0` since it will be normalized ... However this does not solve the actual intempt of rotating the spawned bullet about 90° on the X axis ... And that **is** what the question is about ;)

Comment: I will agree that your answer is more helpful to this person ^^